# Writing list of lists to a text file, one list at a time

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the code below:

```
data=[(24, 'Sale', 0, 15), (16, 'Buy', 18, 0)]
with open('txt_file.txt', 'w') as x:
    for sub_list in data:
        for item in sub_list:  #Since attempt to write whole giv error
            print(item)      
            x.write(str(item) + '   ')
```

How can I get to extract one list from 'data', which is a list of lists, write it in one line and move to next line before extracting the other list? I need the text file to look like:

```
24 Sale 0 15
16 Buy 18 0
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: missing a linefeed, basically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could just write a newline just after exiting the inner loop, and your code would work (even if the last item would have spaces after it).

```
for item in sub_list:  #Since attempt to write whole giv error
    x.write(str(item) + '   ')
x.write('\n')
```

However, built-in `csv` module handles list of strings, integers, whatever, automatically (also handles strings with spaces in it by quoting them):

```
data=[(24, 'Sale', 0, 15), (16, 'Buy', 18, 0)]
with open('txt_file.txt', 'w', newline="") as x:
   csv.writer(x,delimiter=" ").writerows(data)
```

the `writerows` method is able to write a collection of tuples or lists. Exactly what you need. The only difference is that `csv` cannot separate the data by more than one char (multi-char separators aren't allowed). You'll have to make do with 1 space.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The most concise way to do this would be the following:

```
with open('txt_file.txt', 'w') as x:
    x.write('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in data))
```

Comment: But it's not elegant, and your csv solution handles the nitty gritty crap better

Comment: only a raw solution is able to create a multi-spaced separator, that said.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with open('txt_file.txt','wt') as f:
    [f.write(' '.join([str(it) for it in item])+'\n') for item in data]
```

Comment: don't use comprehension just for looping. besides it doesn't work with OP data.

Comment: fixed for OP's case

Comment: please test your solution, because it's not working properly either.

Comment: fixed again, but i agree it's becoming more and more convoluted

Comment: at least it works. Consider `f.writelines` instead of a comprehension. And pass the generator expression to writelines. Much better than using a comprehsnion just for side effect

Answer (score -1):

Mine approach is based on your idea with a bit of adjustments (1. use format template so you can adjust final view and 2) using unpacking.) Final code looks like, apart make proper format template:

```
data=[(24, 'Sale', 0, 15), (16, 'Buy', 18, 0)]
FMT = '{}   {}   {}'

with open('txt_file.txt', 'w') as x:
    for item in data:
        record = FMT.format(*item)
        print(record)
        x.write(record + '\n')
```

Comment: `FMT = '{}   {}   {}'.format({}, {}, {})` ??? why not just `FMT = "{}   {}    {}"` ? plus have you tested your code?

Comment: ahem. There are 4 arguments, not 3. why not including the linefeed in your format?

Comment: that would write properly but not print if not specify end. After all idea still the same buy using format template and unpacking.

Answer (score -2):

`"\n"` does the trick:

```
data=[(24, 'Sale', 0, 15), (16, 'Buy', 18, 0)]
with open('txt_file.txt', 'w') as x:
    for sub_list in data:
        for item in sub_list:  #Since attempt to write whole giv error
            print(item)      
            x.write(str(item) + '   ')
        x.write("\n")
```